# Blocking A Teamcity Build Agent for a Build Pipeline

Tags: linux, teamcity

I'm having 2 agents (one windows and one linux). In my build chain I'm having three build configuration. Linux Build Configuration is sandwiched between windows build configuration. The Build chain is following steps :

1. run build on windows machine, generate one executable file.
2. setup server on Linux Machine.
3. run executable on windows machine, that'll be consuming server that has been built as part of second step on a linux machine.

The Issue here is If there is during third build configuration , linux agent is shown as idle and can be used to build server again by another triggered build chain. I want to block linux agent during whole build chain.

- server on linux machine has to built in every build chain.
  I've done quite a few research on this but couldn't come up with any solid answer. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TeamCity's REST API to enable and disable the agents. Hook the rest call inside your pipeline.
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-Agents